# java array winning algorithm for game

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, swing

For my independent study this semester, I made the game Oh-Mok, which is basically tic tac toe, but on a 15 by 15 board. I used a 2-D array of buttons with switch capabilities to load through a black picture, a white picture, and null (which is just the button unclicked).

I am done with everything, but now I would like to implement a method where a message shows up when a user wins. (PEOPLE PLAY AGAINST OTHER PEOPLE, NOT THE COMPUTER). The problem is, I don't know how to approach constantly updating based on the clicks. I will attach the main game class and the button class below. (I call new start in the main method which loads a start screen).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class OhMok 
{
    //declaring variables
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); 
    WhiteBlackButton board[][] = new WhiteBlackButton[15][15]; 

    //constructor
    public OhMok()
    {
        //creating frame
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Oh-Mok v1.2 by Adam Romano"); 
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(15,15));

        //adding buttons to frame
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++ )
            {
                board[i][j] = new WhiteBlackButton(); 
                board[i][j].setBackground(new Color(238,221,130));
                mainPanel.add(board[i][j]); 
            }

        }

        mainFrame.add(mainPanel); 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new Start(); 
            }
        });
    }
}

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class WhiteBlackButton extends JButton implements ActionListener
{
    //setting variables
    ImageIcon white, black; 
    int value = 0; 

    //constructors
    public WhiteBlackButton()
    {
        //instantiating Image Icons with black/white
        white = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("white.png")); 
        black = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("black.png")); 
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    //on click-event handling
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        value++; 
        value %= 3; 

        //switching between black, white, nothing
        switch(value)
        {
            case 0:
            setIcon(null); 
            break; 

            case 1:
            setIcon(white); 
            break; 

            case 2: 
            setIcon(black); 
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my solution below.

Comment: "my issue is that i do not know how to go about checking the horizontal, vertical, and diagonal wins within the 2-D array.": then you are not "done with everything"

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make a method in the class `OhMok` called `checkForWin` which checks if someone won and performs the appropriate response. Then you can pass your `OhMok` object to the button in the constructor with `board[i][j] = new WhiteBlackButton(this)` and store a reference to it in the `WhiteBlackButton` class. Call that reference with the `checkForWin` button after every button press.

Since you are learning I will not implement this for you; the above strategy should be enough to point you in the right direction. Let me know if it works out!

Comment: my issue is that i do not know how to go about checking the horizontal, vertical, and diagonal wins within the 2-D array.

Comment: i suggest you to split the checking in three different methods, one for each direction. the horizontal and vertical looks simple, then the diagonal is a bit difficult but not impossible. Post your aproach and we can help!

Comment: @aromano31 for the `checkForWin` method i would suggest adding the `value` of each `WhiteBlackButton` object since you are not maintaining a primitive representation of the game state. Assuming player 1's click value is 1 & for player 2 its 2 then if you get a sum==15 then player 1 wins else if you get 30 then player 2 wins. The win conditions would be same for the diagonal case.

Answer (score 1):

> my issue is that i do not know how to go about checking the horizontal, vertical, and diagonal wins within the 2-D array.

## The Slower Approach

There are 2 approaches to this problem. The ***slower way*** which loops through the 15 x 15 array vertically, horizontally and diagonally for every user input.

- 15 vertical, 15 horizontal & 2 diagonal lines equate to `((15+15+2)*15)=` **480** checks per turn.

---

## The Faster Approach

The faster approach requires no looping. You only have to maintain:

- 1 array of size 15 (where size can dynamically follow board size) to store sum of all **rows**.
- 1 array of size 15 (where size can dynamically follow board size) to store sum of all **columns**.
- 2 variables to store the sum of 2 **diagonal** directions (`NW-SE` & `NE-SW`).

1) Initialize all array elements and variables to 0.

2) Customize and add 2 attributes to your JButtons - `rowValue` & `colValue`. Each button will remember its own position.

3) Predefine a prime number as input value for each player (I choose `1` and `17`)

4) Every time a user clicks on an unoccupied button, based on the current user, add the user's input value into the array accordingly.

Let say user 1 choose `row 0`, `column 3`: **[0][3]**. Then you will update as:

```
int[] rowSum = new int[boardSize];
int[] colSum = new int[boardSize];
int diagNwSe = 0, diagNeSw = 0;

rowSum[r] += playerVal;    //where r (rowValue) is 0
colSum[c] += playerVal;    //where c (colValue) is 3
if(r == c)                 //if a diagonal NW-SE button is pressed
    diagNwSe += playerVal; //where playerVal is 1 for player 1, 17 for player 2
if(r+c == boardSize-1)     //if a diagonal NE-SW button is pressed
    diagNeSw += playerVal;
```

**To check for a winner**

```
//Winning num for player 1: 1 * 15 = 15
//Winning num for player 2: 17 * 15 = 255
public boolean getWinner(Player p, int boardSize){
    int win = p.getPlayerVal() * boardSize;  //get winning number for current player
    if(rowSum[r] == win || colSum[c] == win || diagNeSw == win || diagNwSe == win)
        //player wins!
    //nobody wins
}
```

You may also have a `Player` class which keeps a set of "clicked history" so every player has their own set of array to remember which spots they have chosen. If you do that, there is no need to choose a prime number for each player.

Comment: and how do i go about adding rowValue and colValue to my JButton

Comment: @aromano31 Just create a new class and extends JButton. After that just add any attributes you need in your new class.

Comment: @user3437460: you may have missed aromano's re-ask of the very same question, but re-worded, begging others to finish this work for him. That was quickly squelched by the moderators, and I'm surprised that the didn't ban him from the site.